# fetching a particular object from JSON react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-native

I have  created a GET function using to fetch the api to download, however the request made on the api is  not containing the specific nameVid parameter that should download the video,
the following the download function that I have created,

```
  download =async () => { 
    try {
      const response = await fetch('so url');
      const resJson = await response.text();
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        data: resJson.product,
      }, console.log(resJson)); 
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }

  }
```

Upon making the request to api which it is making but it is not fetching the exact is, what else should I add in order to fetch the exact video to download?

the following are my logs with the JSON that it is returning, where I have to fetchbthe nameVid in order to download:

```
{"product": [{"__v": 0, "_id": "5e301696f75182463c6874ed", "color": "Space Grey", "colors": [Array], "description": "6.5-inch Super Retina XDR OLED display
Water and dust resistant (4 meters for up to 30 minutes, IP68)
Triple-camera system with 12MP Ultra Wide, Wide, and Telephoto cameras; Night mode, Portrait mode, and 4K video up to 60fps
12MP TrueDepth front camera with Portrait Mode, 4K video, and Slo-Mo
Face ID for secure authentication and Apple Pay
A13 Bionic chip with third-generation Neural Engine
Fast charge with 18W adapter included
Wireless charging
Manufacturer Detail: Apple Inc, One Apple Park Way, Cupertino, CA 95014, USA", "downloads": 2, "nameImg": "61jgfLBydjL._SL1024_-1580209807807.jpg", "nameVid": "videoplayback (1)-1580209807809.mp4", "price": 99900, "sellerID": "13755902031", "sellerName": "Appario", "size": "5.8-inch", "sizes": [Array], "title": "Apple iPhone 11 Pro", "typeImg": "image/jpeg", "typeVid": "video/mp4", "uploadedOn": "2020-01-28T11:10:14.244Z", "urlImg": "https://atiiproductmediafiles.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/61jgfLBydjL._SL1024_-1580209807807.jpg", "urlVid": "https://atiiproductmediafiles.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/videoplayback+%281%29-1580209807809.mp4"}, {"__v": 0, "_id": "5e30171df75182463c6874ee", "color": "Haze Blue", "colors": [Array], "description": "Rear Camera - 48MP (Primary) + 8MP (Tele-photo)+16MP (Ultrawide) | Front Camera - 16 MP POP-UP Camera
16.9 centimeters (6.67-inch) multi-touch capacitive touchscreen with 3120 x 1440 pixels resolution
Memory, Storage and SIM: 6GB RAM | 128GB internal memory | Dual SIM dual-standby (4G+4G)
Android Oxygen operating system with 2.84GHz Snapdragon 855 octa core processor
4000mAH lithium-ion battery
1 year manufacturer warranty for device and 6 months manufacturer warranty for in-box accessories including batteries from the date of purchase
Box also includes: Power Adapter, Type-C Cable (Support USB 2.0), Quick Start Guide, Welcome Letter, Safety Information and Warranty Card, Logo Sticker, Case, Screen Protector (pre-applied) and SIM Tray Ejector", "downloads": 41, "nameImg": "61FRLa8IFTL._SL1500_-1580209943294.jpg", "nameVid": "videoplayback-1580209943295.mp4", "price": 53999, "sellerID": "13755902031", "sellerName": "OnePlus", "size": "6.67 inch", "sizes": [Array], "title": "OnePlus 7T Pro", "typeImg": "image/jpeg", "typeVid": "video/mp4", "uploadedOn": "2020-01-28T11:12:29.918Z", "urlImg": "https://atiiproductmediafiles.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/61FRLa8IFTL._SL1500_-1580209943294.jpg", "urlVid": "https://atiiproductmediafiles.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/videoplayback-1580209943295.mp4"}, {"__v": 0, "_id": "5e3273ae32213d4ba037042a", "color": "assas", "colors": [Array], "description": "assa", "downloads": 0, "nameImg": "apex-legends-logo-1580364717181.jpg", "nameVid": "videoplayback (2)-1580364717241.mp4", "price": 222, "sellerID": "sas", "sellerName": "sasa", "size": "sdassa", "sizes": [Array], "title": "wws", "typeImg": "image/jpeg", "typeVid": "video/mp4", "uploadedOn": "2020-01-30T06:11:58.768Z", "urlImg": "https://atiiproductmediafiles.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/apex-legends-logo-1580364717181.jpg", "urlVid": "https://atiiproductmediafiles.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/videoplayback%20%282%29-1580364717241.mp4"}], "user": {"__v": 0, "_id": "5e32f1bbe5db08530cae29c8", "address": [], "changes": [], "checkout": [], "like": [], "links": [], "mobile": 8697779335, "orders": [], "registeredOn": "2020-01-30T15:09:47.117Z"}}
```

Do tell me if anything else is required, am stuck with since long now, kindly help, please.

Comment: after fetching and `setState` `this.state.data` contains an array ... so browse (in react dev tools) `this.state.data[0]...`` for details

Comment: link to? react dev tools? google for it / your browser

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting the response to be JSON, then parse the response body as JSON rather then as text like you have right now.

```
const response = await fetch('url');
const resJson = await response.json(); // .json instead of .text
```